# Deserialize certain nested properties into class

Tags: c#, json, json-deserialization, riot-games-api

I have a large `json` file and only want to use certain nested properties, here is the file

```
{
 "type": "champion",
 "format": "standAloneComplex",
 "version": "6.24.1",
 "data": {
    "Aatrox": {
        "version": "6.24.1",
        "id": "Aatrox",
        "key": "266",
        "name": "Aatrox",
        "title": "the Darkin Blade",
        "blurb": "Aatrox is a legendary warrior, one of only five that remain of an ancient race known as 
         the Darkin. He wields his massive blade with grace and poise, slicing through legions in a style 
         that is hypnotic to behold. With each foe felled, Aatrox's ...",
        "info": {
          "attack": 8,
          "defense": 4,
          "magic": 3,
          "difficulty": 4
        },
        "image": {
          "full": "Aatrox.png",
          "sprite": "champion0.png",
          "group": "champion",
          "x": 0,
          "y": 0,
          "w": 48,
          "h": 48
        },
        "tags": [
          "Fighter",
          "Tank"
        ],
    },
    "Ahri": {
        "version": "6.24.1",
        "id": "Ahri",
        "key": "103",
        "name": "Ahri",
        "title": "the Nine-Tailed Fox",
        "blurb": "Unlike other foxes that roamed the woods of southern Ionia, Ahri had always felt a 
            strange connection to the magical world around her; a connection that was somehow incomplete. 
            Deep inside, she felt the skin she had been born into was an ill fit for ...",
          "info": {
             "attack": 3,
             "defense": 4,
             "magic": 8,
             "difficulty": 5
           },
           "image": {
              "full": "Ahri.png",
              "sprite": "champion0.png",
              "group": "champion",
              "x": 48,
              "y": 0,
              "w": 48,
              "h": 48
            },
            "tags": [
               "Mage",
               "Assassin"
            ],
      },
```

It is a very long `json` file. I have a class that is

```
public class Champion
{
    public string id { get; set; }
    public string key { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string title { get; set;}
}
public class ChampionRoot
{
    public Dictionary<string, Champion> champions { get; set; }
}
```

What I am trying to do is start at the properties inside "Data" and only get "id", "key","name" and "title", and `Deserialize` those properties into my `ChampionRoot` class. I have searched and tried many things and cannot get it to work. Here is some of what I've tried in my controller

```
public IActionResult Champions()
{
    var url = @"url.......";
    WebClient client = new WebClient();

    var download = client.DownloadString(url);

    var champions = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ChampionRoot>(download);

    return Json(champions);    //This returns null in the view
}
```

I have also tried using `JObject` a few different ways and that doesn't work for me either

```
JObject obj = JObject.Parse(download);
var json = obj["key"]["id"]["name"]["title"];    //throws object reference error
```

Then I've tried this

```
JObject obj = JObject.Parse(download);
var champions = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ChampionRoot>(obj.ToString());
//This also returns null in the view
```

I have searched and read many answers but I cannot figure it out. The question is how can I only `Deserialize` those 4 nested properties into an object? The url is http://ddragon.leagueoflegends.com/cdn/6.24.1/data/en_US/champion.json for full `json` file.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `Dictionary<string, Champion>` for `data` property:

```
public class ChampionRoot
{
    public Dictionary<string,Champion> data { get; set; }
}
var champions = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ChampionRoot>(download);
```

Comment: Thank you :) Solution i was using earlier was more complicated and was using JProperties and dynamics xD

Comment: This still gives me null when I do it though

Comment: @janzen canyou please add full reproducer. Cause for me it works - [please see yourself](https://dotnetfiddle.net/6h9Dfj)

Comment: is "yousefull" some kind of pun?))))))

Comment: but it was funny as i'm 2 from Russia xDD

Comment: I edited my question, added the full url as it could be that the full url is much larger than this, also I added `Dictionary` instead of `list` in my class

Comment: @janzen rename property `ChampionRoot.champions` to `ChampionRoot.data`, as in my answer.

Comment: Duh I should have saw `data` rather than `champions`. This is works if I remove `.First().id`.Thank you for the help